# Why does rolling occur on a smooth horizontal surface and not on a smooth inclined surface?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

My question is , How can a body roll on a smooth horizontal surface , since friction is necessary for a body to roll.

Comment: Let's say you push a ball, through its center of mass, on a frictionless surface. Will it roll? Realistically, how frictionless can you make a surface (and a ball) so the ball will not roll?

Answer (score 1):

Physics is full of idealisations which don't obtain in practical situations.

A cylinder is said to roll without slipping when if it moves a distance equal to its circumferance then the cylinder has made a single revolution.

Notice here we made no mention of the roughness or the smoothness of the surface. You are correct of course, without friction the cylinder would just slip in place and never roll.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to push a smooth ball on a smooth horizontal surface hard and fast enough, it would slip first and eventually start rolling again. If you push it gently, it would roll rather than slip.

It is a similar case with an inclined surface: The ball can slip because the inclined surface can make the ball go down the surface faster (proportional to the angle of incline and the friction constants of the ball and the surface) which is similar to giving the ball a faster and harder push in the horizontal case.

If you keep the friction constants fixed and just vary the angle of incline, you would see an angle $\phi_1$ that is the maximum angle that can keep the ball rolling, and then you would see another angle $\phi_2$ just above $\phi_1$ where you would see the ball only slip.

You can try this experiment and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

If you had a **perfectly** smooth sphere of radius $r$ and a **perfectly** smooth horizontal surface, you could get the sphere to roll without slipping on the surface if you set the sphere spinning with angular velocity $\omega$ and then projected the sphere along the surface so that the velocity of the centre of the sphere is exactly $v$, where $$v=r\omega.$$
Obviously such a scenario is purely theoretical.

Answer (score 0):

To move a body from rest to motion, a force F must act on it.
Friction only counteracts this force over time and slows down the movement again.

Answer (score 0):

Static friction is only necessary to initiate rolling on a horizontal surface (initial acceleration), or to change the velocity of a body already rolling.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So lets say theres a body is rolling motion on horizontal surface , can it fulfil the conditions of pure rolling without the need of any force of friction?

Comment: @Chemgeek Yes once it is rolling at constant velocity (no forces acting on the body), then there is not need for a friction force. In fact, if there were only a static friction force acting on the body, it would cause its velocity to change.

Comment: "to initiate rolling on a horizontal " from then on there is conservation of angular momentum. It is true for the inclined plane one too, if at the start there is friction.

Answer (score 0):

Friction is not only due to roughness of the surface but also due to intermolecular attraction.So, if the surface is smooth, still there will be a friction. The applied force and friction may form a couple which tends to revolve the sphere

Answer (score 0):

Classical Mechanics: For a cylinder and in the cylinder's reference frame, the motion could be characterized by the

$$\textbf{Linear momentum}\text{(the linear velocity }\vec v \text{ that's moving forward)}\otimes \textbf{Angular momentum} \text{(the angular velocity } \vec \omega \text{ that's rolling)} $$